# ethers.js Why aren't logs filtering? (query returned more than 10000 results)

Tags: events, infura, logs, ethers.js

I'm building an API to scrape events from a contract suite deployed to Rinkeby. Here's an example function with some context:

```
const network = getNetwork(parseInt(`${process.env.CHAIN_ID}`));
const provider = network.name === 'unknown' ?
      new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider('http://localhost:8545/') :
      getDefaultProvider(network);

const tokenInstanceContract = new Contract(`${process.env.TOKEN_ADDRESS}`,
      TokenABI.abi,
      provider);

export async function getAllTxs(address: string = "", total: number = 50, userRole: any = null) {
    const event = tokenInstanceContract.interface.events.Transfer
    const logs = await provider.getLogs({
      fromBlock: process.env.DEPLOYMENT_BLOCK,
      toBlock: 'latest',
      topic: event
    }).catch((err: string) => console.error("BACKEND CATASTROPHE: ", err))
    console.log("YO ITS THE ALL TX LOGS: ", logs);

    return logs
}
```

The contracts were deployed recently. Still when I trigger this function, I get the following back:

```
code: -32005,
  data: undefined,
  url: 'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/{redacted}',
  body: '{"method":"eth_getLogs","params":[{"fromBlock":"0x6a20f3","toBlock":"latest"}],"id":408,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}',
  responseText: '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":408,"error":{"code":-32005,"message":"query returned more than 10000 results"}}'
}
```

I can tell that the function is hitting the Infura API, and seems to be scraping from the parameter passed into `fromBlock`. If that's the case, though, why are there so many results? I mean, even ignoring that the contract doesn't have even close to 10K interactions.

I assume that I'm filtering wrong, but can't figure out how to make this better. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, I was filtering the logs *very* wrong. Let's look at this amazing oopsie from the code block above:

```
const logs = await provider.getLogs({
      fromBlock: process.env.DEPLOYMENT_BLOCK,
      toBlock: 'latest',
      topic: event
    })
```

Note that the `getLogs` is called through the `provider`, not the contract, so in the code above the `getLogs` doesn't "know" to only get `Transfer` events from my specific contract, so instead it tries to return *every ERC20 `'Transfer'` event* since the deployment block of my contract. `getLogs` can also accept an `address` filter, so I should've been doing something like:

```
const logs = await provider.getLogs({
      fromBlock: process.env.DEPLOYMENT_BLOCK,
      toBlock: 'latest',
      address: process.env.MY_CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
      topic: event
    })
```

Which will only return `'Transfer'` events from the address.